# RSA key fingerprint, how to get the password?

Tags: git, gitlab, rsa

I created a workspace in Cloud9 and a repo in gitlab. Now I'm trying to push my stuff from cloud9 to this repo.
So I did:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'some commit message'
$ git remote add origin git@urlToRepo
```

Now I tried to push my stuff and get:

```
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de (xxx.xxx.x.xxx)'
can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is f7:f3:1b:ba:94:16:20:09:71:5c:cf:3c:36:15:a8:f5.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I answered with yes.
Then there came:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de,xxx.xxx.x.xxx'
(RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Then it asked me for a password. But I don't know which password is meant and what it is?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: The password will be gitlab password, for this `git@urlToRepo`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old SSH keys created. The git is already initialized, all you need is to use the pull and push command again.